# artichels_pagination.get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

```py
class artichels_pagination(ListView):

    queryset =models.article.objects.all().order_by('-upload')
    template_name = 'blog.html'
    def get(self,request):
        page_artichel = Paginator(self.queryset, 2)

        page_number = request.GET.get('page')
        page_obj = page_artichel.get_page(page_number)

        render(request,self.template_name,context={'artichel':page_obj})
```

this is error:

```bash
artichels_pagination.get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Comment: how did you register this view in the `urls`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this solution

```py
from django.core.paginator import Paginator


class artichels_pagination(ListView):

    queryset =models.article.objects.all().order_by('-upload')
    template_name = 'blog.html'
    context_object_name = 'articles'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(artichels_pagination, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        articles = self.get_queryset()
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        paginator = Paginator(articles, self.paginate_by)
        try:
            articles = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            articles = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            articles = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        context['articles'] = articles
```